# Generic method for verifying whether a mocked method called

Tags: c#, .net-core, moq, xunit

I am building generic test helper method to verify whether a method is called in the mock with the given type. In my example I am mocking `IMediator` from the library [MediatR](https://github.com/jbogard/MediatR). For mocking I am using [Moq library](https://github.com/moq/moq)

Let's see the code. For the sake of simplicity I made a "dummy" service and a corresponding test, to only focus on the problem.
My production code:

```
public class Service
{
    private readonly IMediator _mediator;

    public Service(IMediator mediator)
    {
        _mediator = mediator;
    }

    public void SendQuery()
    {
        _mediator.Send(new GetAllProductsQuery());
    }
}
```

And the corresponding test:

```
    [Fact]
    public void  WhenSendQueryCalled_ThenGetAllProductsQuerySend()
    {
        //Arrange
        var mockedMediator = new Mock<IMediator>();
        var service = new Service(mockedMediator.Object);

        //Act
        service.SendQuery();

        //Assert
        CheckThatRequestSentViaMediator<GetAllProductsQuery>(mockedMediator);
    }

    private void CheckThatRequestSentViaMediator<TRequest>(Mock<IMediator> mockedMediator) where TRequest : class
    {
        mockedMediator.Verify(mock => mock.Send(It.IsAny<TRequest>(), It.IsAny<CancellationToken>()), Times.Once);
    }
```

My assert method does fail, unexpectedly, with the following reason:

```
Moq.MockException: 
Expected invocation on the mock once, but was 0 times: mock => mock.Send(It.IsAny<GetAllProductsQuery>(), It.IsAny<CancellationToken>())

Performed invocations:

   Mock<IMediator:1> (mock):
```

On the other hand, If I specify the type directly in the verification method, the test passes. The passing assert method looks as the following:

```
    private void CheckGetAllProductsQuerySentViaMediator(Mock<IMediator> mockedMediator)
    {
        mockedMediator.Verify(mock => mock.Send(It.IsAny<GetAllProductsQuery>(), It.IsAny<CancellationToken>()), Times.Once);
    }
```

It looks quite strange to me, since the second assert method works flawlesly. But if I use the generic type parameter and pas it on to the verify method, it fails. What am I doing wrong? Am I not aware of some important underlying behaviour of C#/.NET.Core? Thanks for the help!

Comment: You have double-checked that you are in fact passing in the right type to the generic parameter? For instance, could the real code be separated out over several files, so that the `GetAllProductsQuery` that is in scope for the location of `CheckGetAllProductsQuerySentViaMediator` is not the same one that is in scope for your `WhenSendQueryCalled_ThenGetAllProductsQuerySend`? What happens if you hit F12 (or whatever Go-to-definition key you have in your IDE) on the two `GetAllProductsQuery` in your different pieces of code?You've made sure you don't have 2 copies of the declaration of the type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the problem is with your constraint `where TRequest : class`.

If you look at the `IMediator` you will find two methods:

1. [Receive `IRequest<TResponse>`](https://github.com/jbogard/MediatR/blob/master/src/MediatR/IMediator.cs#L19)
2. [Receive `object`](https://github.com/jbogard/MediatR/blob/master/src/MediatR/IMediator.cs#L27)

It is confusing to **`moq`** to really figure out which override to use. Try being really explicit with the types to really point to the right method, for example:

```
private static void CheckThatRequestSentViaMediator<T>(Mock<IMediator> mediator) 
    where T : IRequest<T>
```

or

```
private static void CheckThatRequestSentViaMediator<T>(Mock<IMediator> mediator) where T : class
{
    mediator.Verify(mock => mock.Send(It.IsAny<IRequest<T>>(), It.IsAny<CancellationToken>()), Times.Once);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer, I appreciate it! Have you tried out your solution? For me, it still does not work, so it fails, unfortunately...

Comment: But given you answer, now I know what the problem, thank you!

Comment: @mirind4 actually I have tried it, weird if it doesn't work...

Comment: I used another abstraction over IRequest<T>, that was the issue.